# Dynamic controls memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

I have a Windows Form application. When I add some buttons to the form dynamically, and then removes those buttons, there is a memory leak.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button[] buttons = new Button[1000];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var b = new Button();
            Controls.Add(b);
            buttons[i] = b;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Controls.Remove(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].Dispose();
            buttons[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Memory usage:

- After form loads: 3720 KB
- After clicking button1: 5144 KB

( These numbers are recorded after performing a full garbage collection. Program was run without debugger, release build.)

Even more strangely, no matter how many times the button1_Click executes, the memory usage stays at around 5100 KB. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the memory stays at 5.1 mb then there is no memory leak. A leak typically means that it doesn't stop at a certain point.

Comment: But why did the memory usage goes up after adding then removing the controls? This is quite weird to me.

Comment: You could try caling `GC.Collect()`. Also, try using a _memory_ profiler like [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler).

Comment: Where are you getting your usage numbers from? An application will hold onto memory even if it's not currently being used, until the OS takes it back.

Comment: Also if I only add those controls without removing them, it uses 5.1 MB memory as well. So I think those 1000 buttons indeed uses 1.4 MB of memory.

Comment: Oh that's a good point. I was just the task manager to get the numbers.

Comment: Since you don't mention, _how_ you measure the memory usage, I guess you simply look at Task Manager. To me, this is a completely unrealistic (read: naïve) approach. Unsing a memory profiler or at least some Performance Counters should be the way to go.

Comment: Applications doesn't release memory on real time. It is fine for your operating system if they keep some extra memory for future usage. We speak about memory leaks when an applications memory usage is growing over time more than necessary AND are not able to release extra memory when the operating system ask it. Look at SQL Server, it will eat over time all free memory and will only decrease when windows will ask free memory for another process. That doesn't mean you need to buy new RAM each day for your server...

Comment: Thank you all for the help. After using a proper memory profiler I can confirm there is no memory leak. The above code works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a memory leak. First of all, if you rely on the Windows Task Manager for this, that's not right. If you really wanna measure the actual memory of your app, try using some performance counters. Or maybe even something like this,

```
private Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
```

Second, even if the objects that are allocated in the heap is collected by the Garbage Collector, after they're disposed, that doesn't mean the application will release the unallocated memory. This will only happen if the operating system requests the wired memory for other operations. The bottom line is, this is not a memory leak.